# using SQLServerBulkCopy for copying data from hive to sql server converts the decimal , float , double value into another value a

Tags: sql-server, scala, hadoop, hive

All the data values greater than 4294967295 are converted to 1 , 2 2tc while saving it to thee SQL Server. We used below code

```
         rowSet.updateBigDecimal(a,

         (BigDecimal(result.getString(a)).setScale(0,BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)).bigDecimal)};

         bulkCopy.setDestinationTableName("tablename");
         bulkCopy.writeToServer(rowSet);
         bulkCopy.close();
```

Comment: What is `SQLServerBulkCopy`? What is the data type in Hive? What is the data type in SQL Server? What kind of connector are you using? Did you check that the `BigDecimal` that you create from something-unknown-converted-to-a-String-just-to-make-things-more-unstable still contains the correct value?

Comment: SQLServerBulkCopy is for copying large bulk data in sql from any source system.The datatype in hive and Sql are decimal(10,0) . The above string as well as ((result.getBigDecimal(a)).setScale(0,BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP)).bigDecimal) gives the correct value but while using the above 3 lines                                                                               bulkCopy.setDestinationTableName("tablename");
         bulkCopy.writeToServer(rowSet);
         bulkCopy.close();converts the data as 4294967295 are converted to 4294967295(correct)  and 4294967296- 0 and 4294967297- 1

Comment: I am using sqljdbc42.jar

Comment: Looks like you are screwed, because your BigInteger gets converted to an "unsigned int" under the covers. Can you pass the String representation instead, using a  SQL `cast()` inside the INSERT statement, so that it's SQL Server that does the conversion and not the driver?